# Find a word in PDF using PDFSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I am using PDFSharp. I need help. I need to check wether the document contains the word "abc". Example:

```
11abcee  = true 
444abcggw = true
778ab = false
```

I wrote this code, but it does not work as expected:

```
    PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open("c:\\abc.pdf");
    PdfDictionary dictionary = new PdfDictionary(document);

    string a = dictionary.Elements.GetString("MTZ");

    if (a.Equals("MTZ"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OK", "");
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("NO", "");
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: _it's does work._ So, isn't that good?

Comment: I've used [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). It works.

Comment: What do you mean by checking *if the document is the word "abc"* ?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but here is an example.

Note: c# 7.0+ is required to use IS new local variable assignment.

Note: This example uses PDFSharp installed from Package Manager.
"Install-Package PdfSharp -Version 1.50.5147"

Note: For my requirements, I only needed to search the first page of my PDFs, update if
needed.

```
using (PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(filePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
{
    if (searchPDFPage(ContentReader.ReadContent(inputDocument.Pages[0]), searchText))
    {
        // match found.
    }
}
```

This code looks for a cString that starts with a pound sign, the OP would need to use a Contains string function.

```
private bool searchPDFPage(CObject cObject, string searchText)
    {
        if (cObject is COperator cOperator)
        {
            if (cOperator.OpCode.Name == OpCodeName.Tj.ToString() ||
                cOperator.OpCode.Name == OpCodeName.TJ.ToString())
            {
                foreach (var cOperand in cOperator.Operands)
                {
                    if (searchPDFPage(cOperand, searchText))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (cObject is CSequence cSequence)
        {
            foreach (var element in cSequence)
            {
                if (searchPDFPage(element, searchText))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (cObject is CString cString)
        {
            if (cString.Value.StartsWith("#"))
            {
                if (cString.Value.Substring(2) == searchText)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Credit: This example was modified based on this answer:
[C# Extract text from PDF using PdfSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141143/c-sharp-extract-text-from-pdf-using-pdfsharp)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this SO entry will help you: [PDFSharp alter Text repositioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144640/alter-pdf-text-repositioning/9161732#9161732).
It links to [here](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=4010#p4010) - text extraction example with PDFSharp.

Comment: FYI the example that is on the PDFSharp forum doesn't work.

Comment: @PeterMoore It's been a while since this question was answered. A lot could happen in 7 years. Do you need help with something in particular or just an observation? Thanks.

Comment: Exactly why I pointed out it no longer works. Just an FYI.